# Can't replicate POST request in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to do a POST request from CasperJS:

```
 for(var i in phantom.cookies)
    cookie += phantom.cookies[i].name + '=' + phantom.cookies[i].value + ';';

 casper.thenOpen(url, {
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        // some form-data
     },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Cookie': cookie
    }
 }, function(response) {
    if(response.status == 200) {
        require('utils').dump(this.page.content);
    }
 });
```

When I execute the request somewhere else I get the appropriate response, but for some reason I can't replicate the output on CasperJS. Here is an example of a cURL request that did work:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cookie: cookie" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "field=field" "url"
```

Comment: What kind of data is your server expecting? Do you need to set the 'content-type' header?

Comment: I added that but it's still not working. I also added a cURL that does work for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

My case was CasperJS (1.1.x version) testing my REST API. API is written in node. In one specific resource I'm processing a form using formiddable. When I set content-type: multipart/form-data in Casper, that formiddable library complains with this error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary

I could not find a solution for this. Instead I ended up doing this in Casper:

```
casper.open(<url>, {
        method: 'POST',
        data: "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\nxxx\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"\r\n\r\nhttps:\/\/url\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
        }
    })
```

basically I formatted the body to the proper format and this worked